# Dual-boot stopped working - Ubuntu 20.04 and Windows 10

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

Installed Windows 10 first, then Ubuntu 20.04 on top, in dual-boot. Worked very well for a few months, suddenly the Windows boot option returned this:

> "error: file '/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi' not found"

I ran `bootinfoscript`, and got this first RESULTS.txt: https://u.pcloud.link/publink/show?code=XZXMYlXZGVTc4SlE7LR0sfdKoPUuORUcRubV

I checked this folder in the EFI System Partition (sdb1), and sure enough there was no "bootmgfw.efi" file there. I got this file from the Windows partition (/Windows/Boot) and tried to copy to the place the grub was looking for, but this is what I got:

> root@i3-4170-ubuntu:/mnt/EFI/Microsoft/Boot# cp -f /home/wolf/bootmgfw.efi /mnt/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/.
>
> cp: cannot create regular file '/mnt/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/./bootmgfw.efi': Read-only file system

Following instructions from a forum post, I went with `sudo update-grub` and the result was:

> Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
>
> Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg'
>
> Generating grub configuration file ...
>
> Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.11.0-27-generic
>
> Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.11.0-27-generic
>
> Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.11.0-25-generic
>
> Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.11.0-25-generic
>
> find: ‘/boot/efi/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/es-ES’: Input/output error
>
> Adding boot menu entry for UEFI Firmware Settings
>
> done

I restarted and, this time, *the Windows boot option did not appear at all*. In fact, the computer booted directly into Ubuntu 20.04, skipping the menu entirely.

I tried `boot-repair`, which was also suggested in a forum. It failed to repair the GRUB, stating that it found a LegacyWindows partition and that a compatibility mode had to be se in the UEFI firmware. I highly doubt it, since I very consciouly installed Windows 10 and Ubuntu on UEFI mode, with Legacy disabled. Plus, it was never a problem for the last few months.

I ran `bootinfoscript` after this, and got this second log, renamed RESULTS-2.txt: https://u.pcloud.link/publink/show?code=XZMxYlXZHrECQn04trJYv3eYKdrNYRIwXuCk

This line from `update-grub` above caught my attention: `find: ‘/boot/efi/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/es-ES’: Input/output error`. But I will not mess with it further until I get some help, if anyone could be so kind.

Comment: Before anything else please check UEFI > Boot. Can you select "Windows bootloader manager" in order to boot Windows directly?

Comment: Thank you! It was one of the first things I tried, and tried again now, with no effect. "Windows bootloader" appears as an option in UEFI boot menu, but it doesn't boot.

Comment: You need to boot a Windows 10 installation USB and repair it. Grub can only boot working Windows. If it doesn't boot directly then it isn't a Grub's or Ubuntu's problem.

Comment: Did it! Worked! Now I can boot both Ubuntu and Windows from UEFI boot menu. Do I try to repair the Grub now? how? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yes, now you should boot Ubuntu and run `sudo update-grub`.

Comment: Done. You're the man! Thanks a bunch.

Comment: Please consider posting an answer with the details of your solution. Our primary goal on Ask Ubuntu is to provide a library of questions and answers about Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved:

-Tried booting into the Windows partition directly from the UEFI Boot Menu. It didn't work.

-Booted into a Windows 10 installation USB pendrive, then "Repair", then "Repair Windows initialization" or something like that. It automatically found the windows partition and repaired it.

-With that, I was able to boot into Windows from the UEFI. I just needed to repair the GRUB, which I did booting into Ubuntu and running `sudo update-grub`

Thanks @ChanganAuto for the help.